# Having an issue connecting to a SQL DB while using pyodbc. Error: SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server DB from Python using pyodbc.  I keep getting the error:

> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

I can't seem to figure out why.  The DB is held on SQL Server 2012.

I'm new to Python, so if I'm making an egregiously silly error I apologize.  So far, I've tried adding a ';' after the password and after the final parentheses.  I've tried using `{SQL Server}` rather than `{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}`.  I've changed `Trusted Connection` to *yes* as well.  There is a username and password on the DB so I to use both.

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', Host = Name-DA\\SQLEXPRESS, database = TestDB, Trusted_Connection = tcon, username = user, password = pwd)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from dbo.ProFormaData")
```

The error reads:

> cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', Host
>   = Name-DA\SQLEXPRESS, database = DBName, Trusted_Connection = tcon, username = user, password = pwd) 
>   ^ SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>   
>  Process returned 1 (0x1)        execution time : 0.075 s  
>  Press
>   any key to continue . . .

Hoping to just print out the data for now.  This is a test for more data manipulation later.

Comment: Can you update with the full error message (complete traceback) and which line of your code the error occurs on?

Comment: Also, where are you defining database? I see Host = database, database = table; I tried running this in my interpreter and received `name 'database' is not defined`.

Comment: jhelphenstine (user:11639518), it reads

Comment: Driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', Host = Name-DA\\SQLEXPRESS, database = dbo.tableName, @jhelphenstine

Comment: @Deepstop I've added the full error message.  The carrot is under the ' ) '

Comment: Are you not quoting the *host* and *database* values? Absolutely do so! In fact, add anything with backslash as a raw string: `Host = r'Name-DA\\SQLEXPRESS'`. BTW - this is not a pyodbc error but a general python syntax error. And if using variables, please add **full** code block to your question (not comments).

Comment: I do have quotes around the 'Name-DA\\SQLExpress' @Parfait

Comment: Please edit your question with a full, runnable (do redact private info of course) code block. As of now, your post do not have quotes and no variables are assigned.

Comment: And, for the record, the backslash character is the Python line-continuation character which implies that the string was unquoted. @Parfait if it is a raw string then double backslash shouldn't be used. Just one or the other.